# Htaccess - manage catch all in multiple directories and one single htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to dispatch all traffic in multiple directories based on a specific keyword.

I have the following directory structure:

```
dotcom/
dotcom/directory1/ (with subdirs)
dotcom/directory2/ (with subdirs)
dotcom/directory3/ (with subdirs)
```

I have a .htaccess file located in dotcom and I would like to redirect everything behind each directory to an index file in each directory.

Example:

```
dotcom/directory1/anything/blabla to dotcom/directory1/index.php
dotcom/directory2/anything/blabla to dotcom/directory2/index.php
dotcom/anythingNotExisting to dotcom/index.php
```

Anything not in one of the existing directories should be redirected to dotcom/index.php

I tried the following for dotcom:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This catches everything

But when I tried to add conditions like the following, I get a 404:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/directory1/(.*)$ directory1/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

With this, if I try to access dotcom/directory1/blabla I have a 404 while if I access dotcom/directory1/ it goes to the right index.php

I have tried to use the full path dotcom/directory1/ but it doesn't help.

Comment: When you configure this in .htaccess, then the path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a slash; the path "prefix" leading to the current directory has already been stripped off at this point.

Comment: ok thanks. I have removed the slash before directory1 but I still have a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules inside `dotcom/.htaccess`:

```bash
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# ignore all rules below this for real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# for URIs starting with know directory paths
RewriteRule ^(directory1|directory2)/(.*)$ $1/index.php?path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# everything else
RewriteRule .+ index.php?path=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice code sir. Could you please do give guide me on your approach on how you got it that OP is looking for real files/directories to block AND how is that everything else rule you caught it sir. Will be grateful to you if you could guide me :)

Comment: See OP wrote: `Anything not in one of the existing directories should be redirected to dotcom/index.php` and showed example rewrites in a code block

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the solution, it's more elegant and future-proof than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I have found something that works with the following:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond HTTPS off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^directory1/(.*)$ /dotcom/directory1/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^directory2/(.*)$ /dotcom/directory2/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dotcom/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This way I'm catching everything from /directoryX/ and redirect it to the root of the directory, everything else go to dotcom